# Do not indicate success when error ignored with On Error Resume Next

Tags: excel, vba

I move files from one SharePoint path to another.

Once the file is moved I want to show "File Moved" in the column next to the filename.

```vb
currRow = 11
On Error Resume Next
For currRow = currRow To LastRow
    Filename = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & currRow).Value
    From_Path = "blabla"
    To_Path = "blabla"
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FSO.MoveFile From_Path & Filename, To_Path & Filename
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & currRow) = "File Moved"
    ThisWorkbook.Save
Next currRow

MsgBox "Files moved"
```

I get "File Moved" for files which did not get moved due to some error.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` just means "ignore any error and execute the next line"

Comment: But, then the file which is not moved should not get "File Moved" comment right?

Comment: Can you  please suggest how to achieve it. If the file is not moved I want to show "Error" on the next column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.  It's best to limit `On Error Resume Next` so you're not ignoring "unexpected" errors in the rest of your code:

```
Dim msg
From_Path = "blabla"
To_Path = "blabla"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For currRow = currRow To LastRow

    Filename = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & currRow).Value
    On Error Resume Next        
    FSO.MoveFile From_Path & Filename, To_Path & Filename
    If Err.Number<>0 Then
        msg = "Error: " & Err.Description
    Else
        msg = "File moved"
    End If
    On Error Goto 0 'limit scope for ignoring errors...     
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & currRow) = msg
    ThisWorkbook.Save
Next currRow
```